# only writing the first row

Tags: sql, postgresql, python-2.7

i'm learning databases and my code doesn't return any error but it only writes the first row. Can you help me? By the way, the link is just an experiment :D
Code :
    page = urllib2.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wushu_at_the_2014_Asian_Games_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_sanda_60_kg")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

```
table = soup.find("table", class_="wikitable")

A = []
B = []
C = []

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='testdb' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='root'")
except:
    print 'Unable to connect to the database.'

cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll("th")
    if len(cells) != 0:
        A.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
        B.append(cells[1].find(text=True))
        C.append(cells[2].find(text=True))
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO test(event_date,event_time,event_event) 
VALUES(%s,%s,%s)""", (A,B,C))
        conn.commit()
```

Comment: Do you have any other error or info about why other lines doesn't works ?

Comment: No, i don't have.

Comment: Are you sure 
<if len(cells) != 0:> is true for other cells? Did you debug?

Comment: Oh, i just tried to make the dataframe and it only appeared the first row also. I just fixed it, i put to search the "th" tags instead of the "td" tags. Thanks :)

Comment: But now happens this: https://prntscr.com/frfyh7

Comment: You called "append" all of your iteration. So it adding new elements on every iteration. You should call "del A[:]" "del B[:]" and "del C[:]" after the conn.commit() line.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It works!

Comment: Your are welcome :) Can you vote my comments?

Comment: You have to answer to upvote. Sorry...

Comment: @oguzhan00 Post your comments as a complete answer so it can be accepted and voted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your

```
if len(cells) != 0:
```

condition is true for your expectation.

Also you should call

```
del A[:] 
del B[:]
del C[:]
```

after the `conn.commit()` line